# How to deselect the selected option in form with Eureka framework

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

How to deselect all the selected options if "Others" is chosen?

```
let fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Guava", "Others"]

form +++= SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>, String>("fruits_section", selectionType: SelectionType.MultipleSelection) { section in
section.header = HeaderFooterView(title: "What is your favorite fruit ?")
}

for fruit in fruits {
    form.last! <<< ImageCheckRow<String>(fruit) { lrow in
        lrow.title = fruit
        lrow.selectableValue = fruit
    }
}
```